# Как сделать, чтобы открывалась страница по раскодированной ссылке?

Tags: url, php

У меня есть страничка с ссылками такого вида:

```
http://sait.ru/go.php?url=aHR0cDovL3VsLnRvL2xhMmxwbWxo
```

В файле go.php написано:

```
<?php
$url=isset($_REQUEST['url']) ? $_REQUEST['url'] : '';
echo base64_decode($url);
?>
```

При нажатии на `http://sait.ru/go.php?url=aHR0cDovL3VsLnRvL2xhMmxwbWxo`
получается страница с раскодированной ссылкой `http://ul.to/la2lpmlh` простым текстом.

Как мне сделать, чтобы открывалась страница по этой ссылке?

Comment: @Михаил Лобачёв, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `echo...` поставь `header('Location: '.base64_decode($url));`.

**Обновление**

Значит в файле перед header выводится какой-то текст, возможно, пробелы.

Comment: А так ошибка:
 
>PHP SCRIPT ERROR!

>Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/us8963/sait.ru/www/go.php:5) in /home/us8963/sait.ru/www/go.php on line 7

   >If you beleive that this error is due to the server configuration problems please contact your local web-hosting support team.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно будет сделать вот так:

```
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? base64_decode($_GET['url']) : null;

header('Location: '.$url);
exit;
```

И желательно вынести это в отдельный файл, где будут только эти строки, и тогда точно не будет ошибок.

**UPD:**
И убедись, что файл сохранен в `UTF-8 без BOM`, чтобы уже наверняка.

Comment: Всё в файле go.php.  
Выходит таже фигня:

>PHP SCRIPT ERROR!

>Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/us8963/sait.ru/www/go.php:5) in /home/us8963/sait.ru/www/go.php on line 7

Что делать с этим?

Comment: @Михаил Лобачёв последнюю строку моего ответа прочитай.

Comment: Ничего не меняется.
В адресной строке остаётся ссылка в таком виде: http://sait.ru/go.php?url=aHR0cDovL3VsLnRvL2xhMmxwbWxo

И та же ошибка.

Comment: @Михаил Лобачёв прочитайте http://cannot-modify-header-information.ru

Comment: Спасибо, всё решилось. ) В php-файле были лишние пробелы. )